# Simple `Read` instance incorrectly `read`s

Tags: haskell

Why does this Read instance parse inconsistently?

```
import qualified Data.List as List

data Foo = Foo

instance Show Foo where
  show _ = "Foo"

instance Read Foo where
  readsPrec _ s = case List.stripPrefix "Foo" s of
    Just rest -> [(Foo, rest)]
    Nothing -> []
```

This is expected:

```
Test> reads "" :: [(Foo, String)]
[]
```

This is unexpected:

```
Test> read "" :: Foo
Foo
```

I would expect it to throw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't in `read`, but in `show`. Your `show` implementation doesn't force the input value of type `Foo`, because it returns `"Foo"` unconditionally, without even matching a constructor. If you use the derived `Show` instance, or write its equivalent by hand:

```
instance Show Foo where
  show Foo = "Foo"
```

then you will get the expected error when you try to parse a malformed string, because evaluating `show` will actually require parsing the input string.